# How do I communicate between 2 Python programs using sockets that are on separate NATs?

Tags: python, sockets, nat

I want to send and receive messages between two Python programs using sockets. I can do this using the private IPs when the computers are connected to the same router, but how do I do it when there are 2 NATs separating them?

Thanks *(my first SO question)*

Comment: Is this client-server or peer-to-peer?

Comment: Is it a kind of backdoor what you are looking for? Give a try to pwnat (C Code but you can easily integrate with your python program since it is compiled in your OS) ---> http://samy.pl/pwnat/

Comment: peer-to-peer for a decentralised 2 player game. just looking for something with no setup required, players can input an ip they want to play against and the code takes care of it. don't want to have to use servers or setup port forwarding in NAT tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it in general without a relay server on a publicly addressable IP address. There are so-called "punchthrough" techniques that can, in some cases, let you switch to a direct connection after using a public server to figure out port mappings - [this article](http://www.raknet.net/raknet/manual/natpunchthrough.html) describes how the RakNet game networking library does it - but even these tend to be finicky and unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

Zeromq, is the way to go. It is blazing fast and very easy. http://www.zeromq.org/

Answer (score 0):

Redis, could work but not the exact same functionality.